# How does one pre-load a clojure file in the leiningen repl?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

I have some clojure functions that I would like pre-loaded when I start the clojure REPL. The functions aren't much use unless you are using them within the context of a REPL.

If it helps, I generally use leiningen to start a clojure REPL for me.

How can I tell clojure (or leiningen, if it's not available through flat clojure) to pre-load a clojure file containing these definitions for me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several ways to do this described in [the leiningen sample project](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj)
one of my favorite methods is so put the code you want in the default repl namespace into

/path/to/project/dev/user.clj:

```
(ns user)
(def foo 42)
```

and add a line like this into the project.clj file:

```
(defproject hello "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]
  :source-paths ["dev"])
```

This makes it clear that this is for dev while still getting it loaded into the default namespace.

When you run `nrepl-jack-in` form emacs or "lein repl" form the shell, you should be greeted with a `user>` namespace with your code loaded:

```
; nREPL 0.1.6
user> foo
42
```

Comment: +1 for the excellent link. Could you also include in your answer a way to do this for _any_ project (e.g., using '~/.lein/profiles.clj') and also assume that I'm not using emacs (i.e., no 'nrepl-jack-in', just the normal terminal screen)?

Comment: Added part of this to the anwser, and for settings this globally it may be preferable to use :repl-options :init in a profile in your .lein/profiles.clj to using defining a user namespace.

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate if you put the extra `:source-paths` entry inside a profile.  The `:dev` profile would be particularly appropriate I think.  As the answer stands, whatever code is under `dev` while still be included in the project all the time.

Comment: I had to include `"src"` too: `:source-paths ["src" "dev"]` otherwise I could load my namespaces.