# leinigen repl with profile

Tags: clojure, leiningen

This question is a follow up to [How does one pre-load a clojure file in the leiningen repl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551918/how-does-one-pre-load-a-clojure-file-in-the-leiningen-repl).

My `~/.lein/profiles.clj` looks as follows:

```
{  
  :user {:source-paths ["C:/Users/username/.lein/src"] }
}
```

My `~/.lein/src/user.clj` might look as follows:

```
(ns user)

(println "user file loaded")
```

When I run `lein repl` within a folder containing a `project.clj`, then the `user.clj` file is executed, but when I run `lein repl` from another folder it doesn't load my user profile. Is there a workaround for this or is this behavior by design? In fact, I know that Leinigen is indeed loading my `profile.clj` (even when there is no project.clj) because there are also other things inside (taken from the excellent [pimp my repl](http://dev.solita.fi/2014/03/18/pimp-my-repl.html) article). Leinigen is just having problems with my additional source-paths setting.

One other question related to this is the fact that I need to specify the full path of the folder for my `user.clj` file : `"C:/Users/username/.lein/src"`. When I change that to `"~/.lein/src"` leiningen fails to load my file.

Comment: Do you see anything in the documentation to suggest that `~` in a source-path should work? In general tilde expansion only works in Linux shells - I wouldn't expect it to work from within Java, or on a Windows platform.

Comment: Good catch: Replaced it with {:source-paths [~(str (System/getProperty "user.home") "/.lein/src")]} and it works. But I still can't use it from a folder without a project.clj inside it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you just want some code loaded for your `lein repl` sessions. This is done with the `:init` key of the `:repl-options` in your `profiles.clj`. You can `load-file` other files in `init` if you want to organize in that fashion.

```
{:user 
  {:repl-options 
    {:init (load-file "path-to-file/user.clj")} 
     ...}}
```

Note: If you are using Windows-style path delimiters `/`, you'll need to escape them `//`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. The following snippet works for me, including the loading of scripts relative to my home dir: {:user {:repl-options {:init (load-file (str (System/getProperty "user.home") "/.lein/src/user.clj"))}}}

Comment: Ah, I'm working via Cygwin on Windows, kind of assumed you were too with the "~/" path references.